# Can we do anything about users recreating their account?

Tags: discussion

I notice very often (usually when checking the suggested edits) that some users tend to edit their question with a new account with the same username.

I know it is allowed to have several accounts but I have wondering if we could maybe help them merging their account as it sounds to me like they just forgot their password or something like this.

Comment: There is option for `forgot their password `. i always used that after my session expire..

Comment: @QaisarSatti interesting approach to password management :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no. There's nothing that can be done. I can't see a reason why an edit would be gaming the system unless the user had been removed and recreated an account to continue to harass or otherwise break our content policies.

In these cases I think we just watch and monitor that it's not abuse.